# Svg path arrowhead without use of marker

Tags: javascript, svg

I would like to create arrow head at beginning and end of a SVG path or line without the use of markers.
This way i can manipulate the arrow with only css (mouseover)

Using the path as input for a javascript function, i'm assuming it should be possible to use the begin/end coordinates to draw a polygon (arrowhead).

Comment: Sounds interesting. As SVG is a language for plotting paths, and displaying "graphics", can you add more detail to your question?

Comment: CSS hover states are not supported very well on SVG sub-elements, so you're going to be using Javascript whatever you do.

Comment: Use an SVG editor such as Inkscape and draw whatever you want,

Comment: @RobertLongson It's a javascript project where i'm drawing SVG paths dynamically based on certain data. At the beginnen and end of certain paths i need to add an arrowhead polygon.

I managed to do it by using the begin/end coordinate and the angle of the line to determine my polygon points, but i'm not happy with the code just yet.

By drawing my own polygon as part of my line (group) i can manipulate everything from css

Comment: If you have code, show it to us. Explain what part of it you're unhappy with.

Comment: @RobertLongson I was still fiddling around. I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
// Determine polygon points
beginArrowPoints(pathCoords: { x: number; y: number }[]) {
  return this.getPolygonCoords(pathCoords, 0);
}

endArrowPoints(pathCoords: { x: number; y: number }[]) {
  return this.getPolygonCoords(pathCoords, pathCoords.length - 1);
}

// set rotation on transform
rotateBegin(pathCoords: { x: number; y: number }[]) {
  const endPoint = pathCoords[1];
  const startPoint = pathCoords[0];
  const angleDeg = this.determineRotationAngle(endPoint, startPoint);
  return `rotate(${angleDeg}, ${startPoint.x}, ${startPoint.y})`;
}

rotateEnd(pathCoords: { x: number; y: number }[]) {
  const endPoint = pathCoords[pathCoords.length - 1];
  const startPoint = pathCoords[pathCoords.length - 2];
  const angleDeg = this.determineRotationAngle(endPoint, startPoint);
  return `rotate(${angleDeg}, ${endPoint.x}, ${endPoint.y})`;
} 

private determineRotationAngle(endPoint: { x: number; y: number }, startPoint: { x: number; y: number }) {
  const deltaX = Math.abs(endPoint.x - startPoint.x);
  const deltaY = endPoint.y - startPoint.y;
  return Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI + 180; // invert by turning 180 degrees
}

private getPolygonCoords(pathCoords: { x: number; y: number }[], index: number) {
  const {x, y} = pathCoords[index];
  const p1 = `${x} ${y}`;
  const p2 = `${x + 7.5} ${y + 5}`;
  const p3 = `${x + 7.5} ${y - 5}`;
  return `${p1}, ${p2}, ${p3}`;
}
```

Resulting in a polygons like:

```
<g>
   <polygon id="start" points="240 0, 247.5 5, 247.5 -5" ="rotate(180, 240, 0)"></polygon>
   <polygon id="end" points="1038 694.32, 1045.5 699.32, 1045.5 689.32" transform="rotate(235.4921735667412, 1038, 694.32)"></polygon>
   
   <path d="M240,0L330,0L402,29.82L507,158.32L522,174.82L690,320.94L720,320.94L792,372.32L819,405.52L825,411.92L852,445.48L936,556.32L987,618.96L990.0000000000001,624.5L1038,694.32" ></path>
</g>
```

Styling and event handling can then be done on the whole group